Optimizing node placement in a 2D grid to match specific geodesic distances
I'm working on a problem where I need to arrange a set of nodes within a 2D grid such that the distance between pairs of nodes either approximate specific values as closely as possible or meet a minimum threshold.
In other words, for some node pairs, the distance should be approximately equal to a predefined value (≈). For other node pairs, the distance should be greater than or equal to a predefined threshold (≥).
Additional challenge: the grid is inscribed inside a concave polygon, so distances must be geodesic.
Question: Using OR-Tools, how can I efficiently approximate the location of the nodes given the constraints above-mentioned?

[EDIT] I've revised the example script, trying as best I can to apply Laurent's wise suggestions, but my poor understanding of OR-Tools (and its subtleties) still makes this a very difficult task.
This version:

creates a simple conforming grid
pre-computes geodesic distances between all pairs of cells within that grid
indicates the number of nodes to place as well as their associated target pairwise distances

each pairwise distance comes with an objective to match (either ≈ or ≥)


declares the CP-SAT model and creates the main variables for the problem
(new) ensures each node is assigned exactly to one position and each position can have at most one node
(new) creates a Boolean variable checking if the distance constraint is met for each pair of nodes
(new) use AddImplication to connect the Boolean variables with the node positions
(new) applies conditional penalties based on whether the distance condition is met and tries to minimize their sum

Unfortunately, I must be missing a few nuances because this implementation doesn't return any results even though the solution space not null.
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx

# Dimensions of the original grid (width & height)
w, h = 7, 5

# Selection of grid-cell indices (conforming/concave grid)
cell_indices = list(sorted(set(range(w * h)) - set([0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 28, 29])))


# Topology of the conforming/concave grid
T = nx.Graph()

for i in cell_indices:
    if i >= w and (i - w) in cell_indices:
        T.add_edge(i, i - w, weight=1)
    if i < w * (h - 1) and (i + w) in cell_indices:
        T.add_edge(i, i + w, weight=1)
    if i % w != 0 and (i - 1) in cell_indices:
        T.add_edge(i, i - 1, weight=1)
    if (i + 1) % w != 0 and (i + 1) in cell_indices:
        T.add_edge(i, i + 1, weight=1)
    
# Precompute geodesic distances using Dijkstra's algorithm
geodesic_distances = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(T))


# Get the largest geodesic distance 
max_distance = float('-inf')
for i1 in geodesic_distances:
    for i2 in geodesic_distances[i1]:
        if i1 != i2 and i1 > i2:
            distance = geodesic_distances[i1][i2]
            if distance > max_distance: max_distance = distance

            
# Number of nodes to place
num_nodes = 5

# Target distances to match between each pair of nodes + type of objective (≈ or ≥)
objective_distances = {(0, 1): (3, '≈'),
                       (0, 2): (2, '≥'),
                       (0, 3): (2, '≥'),
                       (0, 4): (3, '≈'),
                       (1, 2): (3, '≥'),
                       (1, 3): (3, '≥'),
                       (1, 4): (4, '≥'),
                       (2, 3): (2, '≈'),
                       (2, 4): (4, '≥'),
                       (3, 4): (3, '≈')}


# Instantiate model
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Ensure each position can have at most one node
node_at_position = {}
for index in cell_indices:
    at_most_one = []
    for node in range(num_nodes):
        var = model.NewBoolVar(f'node_{node}_at_position_{index}')
        node_at_position[node, index] = var
        at_most_one.append(var)
    
    # Apply at most one node per position constraint
    model.AddAtMostOne(at_most_one)

# Ensure each node is assigned exactly to one position 
for node in range(num_nodes):
    model.AddExactlyOne(node_at_position[node, idx] for idx in cell_indices)


penalties = []

# For each pair of nodes:
for (node1, node2), (target_distance, constraint_type) in objective_distances.items():
    
    # For each compatible pair of cells
    for i1, i2 in combinations(cell_indices, 2):
        
        # Get the corresponding geodesic distance
        distance = geodesic_distances[i1][i2]
        
        # Create a Boolean variable
        is_compatible = model.NewBoolVar(f'compat_{node1}_{node2}_{i1}_{i2}')
        
        # Create a penalty variable
        penalty = model.NewIntVar(0, max_distance, f'penalty_{node1}_{node2}_{i1}_{i2}')
        
        if constraint_type == '≈':
                        
            # Condition that `is_compatible` will be True if the distance approximates (deviation: -1/+1) the target distance
            model.Add(is_compatible == (target_distance - 1 <= distance <= target_distance + 1))
              
        elif constraint_type == '≥':
            
            # Condition that `is_compatible` will be True if the distance is at least the target distance
            model.Add(is_compatible == (distance >= target_distance))
       
        
        # If 'is_compatible' is true -> implications to enforce node positions
        model.AddImplication(is_compatible, node_at_position[node1, i1])
        model.AddImplication(is_compatible, node_at_position[node2, i2])
        
        # If it is not -> add a penalty
        model.Add(penalty == abs(distance - target_distance)).OnlyEnforceIf(is_compatible.Not())
            
        # Accumulate penalties
        penalties.append(penalty)
                
      
# Objective to minimize total penalty
model.Minimize(sum(penalties))

# Solving the model
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)


print("Solver status:", solver.StatusName(status))    
    
if status == cp_model.FEASIBLE or status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    print("Solution found:")
    for node in range(num_nodes):
        for index in cell_indices:
            if solver.Value(node_at_position[node, index]):
                print(f'Node {node} is at position {index}')
else:
    print("No solution found.")


I think you are now going astray by using a variable for compatibility.  You know which nodes are compatible for each type of requirement--no determination by the solver is required, and this is huge model bloat.  You should be subsetting your node pairs into 2 subsets:  compatible with the approx equal reqt. and compatible with the GTE reqt.  No variables required.  Then, you should be making constraint that each placement reqt. of appropriate type must occur within those subsets.

If you're not beholden to ortools, here is a solution using pyomo and HiGHS solver.  Minimally, this might give you some insights on the correct ortools syntax to implement some of these types of constraints, if this formulation works.  I'm not familiar w/ the ortools syntax, but this aligns with the context of what @Laurent Perron mentioned above.
This is a pretty stout BIP (Binary Integer Program) and I've put an absolute gap in the solve such that if it gets within 1.0 of the theoretical limit, it will stop rather than continuing the solve.  With that, it pops out an optimal answer in about 10 minutes on my machine, with the solution shown at bottom with a total penalty of 3 distance units for the example shown.
Code:
"""
placing nodes within a grid
Created on:  5/31/24
"""
from collections import defaultdict

import pyomo.environ as pyo
import highspy
import networkx as nx

# Dimensions of the original grid (width & height)
w, h = 7, 5

# Selection of grid-cell indices (conforming/concave grid)
cell_indices = list(sorted(set(range(w * h)) - {0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 28, 29}))

# Topology of the conforming/concave grid
T = nx.Graph()

for i in cell_indices:
    if i >= w and (i - w) in cell_indices:
        T.add_edge(i, i - w, weight=1)
    if i < w * (h - 1) and (i + w) in cell_indices:
        T.add_edge(i, i + w, weight=1)
    if i % w != 0 and (i - 1) in cell_indices:
        T.add_edge(i, i - 1, weight=1)
    if (i + 1) % w != 0 and (i + 1) in cell_indices:
        T.add_edge(i, i + 1, weight=1)

# Precompute geodesic distances using Dijkstra's algorithm
geodesic_distances = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(T))

# Get the largest geodesic distance
max_distance = float('-inf')
for i1 in geodesic_distances:
    for i2 in geodesic_distances[i1]:
        if i1 != i2 and i1 > i2:
            distance = geodesic_distances[i1][i2]
            if distance > max_distance: max_distance = distance

# Number of nodes to place
num_nodes = 5

# Target distances to match between each pair of nodes + type of objective (≈ or ≥)
objective_distances = {(0, 1): (3, '≈'),
                       (0, 2): (2, '≥'),
                       (0, 3): (2, '≥'),
                       (0, 4): (3, '≈'),
                       (1, 2): (3, '≥'),
                       (1, 3): (3, '≥'),
                       (1, 4): (4, '≥'),
                       (2, 3): (2, '≈'),
                       (2, 4): (4, '≥'),
                       (3, 4): (3, '≈')
                       }

# print(geodesic_distances)

# let's chop up the pairs into needed subsets, and hook them up to penalty values
fudge_factor = 1.0   # the max allowable miss for ≈ constraints
cutoff_points = [t[0] for t in objective_distances.values()]

ge_pairs = defaultdict(dict)  # GTE pairs at cutoff point
ae_pairs = defaultdict(dict)  # Approx Equal pairs at cutoff point
for idx in cell_indices:
    for other, dist in geodesic_distances[idx].items():
        if other <= idx:
            continue  # we only need "sorted" pairs like the objective_distances
        for c in cutoff_points:
            if dist >= c:
                ge_pairs[c][idx, other] = dist - c
            if c - fudge_factor <= dist <= c + fudge_factor:
                ae_pairs[c][idx, other] = abs(dist - c)

# now bin up the requirements as basis for the associated constraints
ge_reqts = {}
ae_reqts = {}
for (n1, n2), (c, c_type) in objective_distances.items():
    if c_type == '≈':
        ae_reqts[n1, n2] = c
    elif c_type == '≥':
        ge_reqts[n1, n2] = c
    else:
        raise ValueError()


# on to the model...
m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# === SETS ===
m.G = pyo.Set(initialize=cell_indices, doc='Grid Points')
m.GG = pyo.Set(initialize=[(g1, g2) for g1 in m.G for g2 in m.G if g2 > g1], doc=('paired '
                                                                                 'assignment at '
                                                                                  'g_1, g_2)'))
m.N = pyo.Set(initialize=list(range(num_nodes)), doc='Nodes')
m.NN = pyo.Set(initialize=objective_distances.keys(), doc='assignment requirements')

def eligible_assignments(m, *nn):
    # a helper function to determine (limit) assignments to eligible spots
    if nn in ae_reqts:
        cutoff = ae_reqts[nn]
        eligible_locations = ae_pairs[cutoff]
        return eligible_locations
    if nn in ge_reqts:
        cutoff = ge_reqts[nn]
        eligible_locations = ge_pairs[cutoff]
        return eligible_locations
m.eligible_locations = pyo.Set(m.NN, initialize=eligible_assignments)
m.NNGG = pyo.Set(initialize=[(nn, gg) for nn in m.NN for gg in m.eligible_locations[nn]])

# === VARS ===
m.place = pyo.Var(m.N, m.G, domain=pyo.Binary, doc='place node N at point G')
m.paired_assignment = pyo.Var(m.NNGG, domain=pyo.Binary, doc='node pair assigned to grid pair')

# === OBJ ===
# helper expressions
ge_penalties = sum(m.paired_assignment[nn, gg] * ge_pairs[ge_reqts[nn]][gg] for nn in ge_reqts for gg
                   in m.eligible_locations[nn])
ae_penalties = sum(m.paired_assignment[nn, gg] * ae_pairs[ae_reqts[nn]][gg] for nn in ae_reqts for gg
                   in m.eligible_locations[nn])

# the OBJECTIVE
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=ge_penalties + ae_penalties, sense=pyo.minimize)


# === CONSTRAINTS ===

@m.Constraint(m.N)
def assign_exactly_once(m, n):
    return sum(m.place[n, g] for g in m.G) == 1

@m.Constraint(m.G)
def max_one_per_grid_point(m, g):
    return sum(m.place[n, g] for n in m.N) <= 1

@m.Constraint(m.NNGG)
def link_assignment(m, n1, n2, *gg):
    return m.paired_assignment[n1, n2, gg] <= sum(m.place[n1, g] + m.place[n2, g] for g in gg)/2

@m.Constraint(m.NN)
def assign_pair_once(m, *nn):
    return sum(m.paired_assignment[nn, gg] for gg in m.eligible_locations[nn]) == 1


# === QA ===
# m.pprint()

# === SOLVE ===
opt = pyo.SolverFactory('appsi_highs')
res = opt.solve(m, options={'mip_abs_gap': 1.1}, tee=True)
# abs gap implies that if we get within 1.0 of theoretical limit, that's good enough to stop.

if pyo.check_optimal_termination(res):
    print('Optimal termination')
    print(res)

    print(' --- placements ---')
    for n in sorted(m.N):
        for g in m.G:
            if pyo.value(m.place[n, g]) > 0.5:
                print(f'place {n} at {g}')

    print(' --- pairing penalties ---')
    for nngg in m.NNGG:
        if pyo.value(m.paired_assignment[nngg]) > 0.5:
            nn = nngg[:2]
            gg = nngg[2:]
            if nn in ge_reqts:
                c = ge_reqts.get(nn, None)
                penalty = ge_pairs[c][gg]
                print(f'assign {nn} to (unordered) {gg} for penalty {penalty}', end='')
            else:
                c = ae_reqts.get(nn, None)
                penalty = ae_pairs[c][gg]
                print(f'assign {nn} to (unordered) {gg} for penalty {penalty}', end='')
            print(f' (dist: {geodesic_distances[gg[0]][gg[1]]})')

else:
    print('failed solve ... see log')

Output:
...
Solving report
  Status            Optimal
  Primal bound      3
  Dual bound        2
  Gap               33.33% (tolerance: 36.67%)
  Solution status   feasible
                    3 (objective)
                    0 (bound viol.)
                    0 (int. viol.)
                    0 (row viol.)
  Timing            782.32 (total)
                    0.28 (presolve)
                    0.00 (postsolve)
  Nodes             170202
  LP iterations     6791616 (total)
                    493334 (strong br.)
                    682673 (separation)
                    357533 (heuristics)
Optimal termination

Problem: 
- Lower bound: 2.0
  Upper bound: 3.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 0
  Number of variables: 0
  Sense: 1
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: TerminationCondition.optimal
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

 --- placements ---
place 0 at 33
place 1 at 12
place 2 at 27
place 3 at 25
place 4 at 31
 --- pairing penalties ---
assign (0, 1) to (unordered) (12, 33) for penalty 0 (dist: 3)
assign (0, 2) to (unordered) (27, 33) for penalty 0 (dist: 2)
assign (0, 3) to (unordered) (25, 33) for penalty 0 (dist: 2)
assign (0, 4) to (unordered) (31, 33) for penalty 1 (dist: 2)
assign (1, 2) to (unordered) (12, 27) for penalty 0 (dist: 3)
assign (1, 3) to (unordered) (12, 25) for penalty 0 (dist: 3)
assign (1, 4) to (unordered) (12, 31) for penalty 1 (dist: 5)
assign (2, 3) to (unordered) (25, 27) for penalty 0 (dist: 2)
assign (2, 4) to (unordered) (27, 31) for penalty 0 (dist: 4)
assign (3, 4) to (unordered) (25, 31) for penalty 1 (dist: 2)

Process finished with exit code 0


Thank you so much for this comprehensive answer. Being a total stranger to the world of OR, and having no prior experience of the various environments and "solvers" available, it took me a while to digest all this information. Thanks again for your time, it was a very instructive read.

I would not do it that way.
Create all ordered pairs of points. (i, j), and (j, i).
For each pair, compute the geodesic distance.
Now, look at your demand and your constraint:
for (a, b) == k: create 1 bool var for every compatible pair of points
for (a, b) >= k, create 1 bool var for every compatible pair of points and add the term bool_var * penalty of this selection.
Now, you just need to add all the at_most_one constraints to maintain consistency. It is a bit tricky to get them all but something like:
for each node and each position: create 1 bool_var. Add an exactly_one constraint on all points for 1 node, add 1 at_most_one for all nodes for 1 point. Then add implications (pair a, b uses node i, j) implies (a, i) == true, and (b, j) == true.
Finally minimize the sum of penalties.

In its current state, the model returns "infeasible". Several pairs share the same node (0-1, 0-2, 0-3, etc) so AddImplication is probably conflicting with position constraints (AddAtMostOne and AddExactlyOne).

You will need to have something like: (a, i) => or(all assignments where a is on i), then not(a, i) => and(not(all assignments when a is on i)). as I said, this is a bit tricky to write correctly.
